# Data Synchronization

Tags: trends

I'm working on market trends. I have daily prices for 33 assets from different markets. I was wondering if there is a way to cancel the effects of different opening/closing times.

I have been told that a moving average over four days would be enough; I think a weekly moving average should improve many thing. As I observe a 50-day moving average to observe market trends, I don't really see the point in doing this first moving average.

Is there any literature about this topic? Are there simple solutions to cancel the effects of markets desynchronization?

Comment: Time scale transformations
http://www.olsen.ch/fileadmin/Publications/Working_Papers/950920_NonLinTimeScale.pdf  If this fits your needs, Olsen has a few more papers on this topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Effects of non-contemporaneous trading (i.e. different closing times) for risk management are covered in this article ([preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3638),[link to journal](http://www.risk.net/journal-of-risk/journal/2164360/issue-volume-14-spring-2012)).

The conclusion is that a moving average process in the sense of time-series analysis can handle the resulting cross-autocorrelation. This means that in each time-step you have lagged correlations (e.g. Japan today to US yesterday) but only for lag $1$.

In case you want to use e.g. [the Hodrick-Prescott-filter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick-Prescott-Filter) in a Kalman filter setting for fitting a trend, this model approach could improve the picture (I can not tell from experience but as an idea ...). For hints on the HP-filter you can start [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/state-space-formulation-of-hodrick-prescott-lter).

Comment: What is the advantage of Hodrick-Prescott-filter over kalman filter ? Am I supposed to use filter before or after modelising ?

Comment: The Kalman filter is a general framework and the HP-filter can be described by means of the Kalman filter (pls. look into my link). Concerning before/after modeling: the filter "is" the model. The filter gives you a model for the trend.

Comment: as you decided to take a try with HP filter - it is already implemented in a much better way then usually described in a books, fastest version of HP can be found here http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?lid=136 (written in C) and here http://www.mql5.com/en/code/143 (written in MQL and also you can see there how this "model" should look like)

Comment: @Richard I was just trying to do this again recently. Fitting VMA(1) model to daily returns for about 10 series using R packages, both MTS and bigtime. I gave up on MTS on Friday. bigtime's version has been running all morning on my work machine. Any hints to make this go faster?

Comment: @John fitting a  VMA(1) takes that long? I am not doing any time series modelling these days. Looking at Hyndman's online textbook (https://otexts.org/fpp2/VAR.html) he mentions the vars package only. Do you think strictly need a VMA(1) or a VAR(1) would also do?

Comment: @Richard Well, it's daily data going back to 1988, so like 8000 data points (edit: on time dimension) or something like that. vars does not fit VMA-style models, only like VAR/SVAR. I was trying VMA(1) based on your comment below about it being better than VAR(1) theoretically. I'm probably going to give it until the end of the day and see if it finishes (of course, it could also be that my work machine is not good enough).

Comment: @Richard I actually seem to be have made good progress by imposing some factor structure on the VMA. In particular, I split it into three blocks, Americas, Europe, and Asia. This simplifies things to a 3-dimensional problem. I then assume America is exposed to Europe and Asia and Europe is exposed to Asia. That leaves just three parameters to estimate, vs. 100 in the original VMA.

Comment: @John: if you use all data back to 1988: do you think the process has been stationary for 30 years? The world has changed along the way :) I never used too long histories myself ... just wanted to point you to the question of "stationarity".

Comment: @Richard I'm investigating the spillover of idiosyncratic Emerging Market shocks to global, so my next step was to fit some kind of multivariate stochastic volatility model. So I wasn't ever planning to assume that volatility is constant over time. Though I would have assumed that means were more-or-less.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to convert the daily series to weekly. Alternately, if you have to use the daily data, [this paper](http://www.axiomainc.com/downloads/Axioma_ReturnsTiming_ShortVersion20101116.pdf) describes how to construct a synchronized return, which you could presumably adjust it into a synchronized hypothetical price.

In general, the issue is one of missing data, which can quickly get you into some advanced techniques (e.g. generating the missing data in a Gibbs sampling approach). The Kalman Filter approach that Richard mentioned also is popular in the literature. In economics, they use Kalman filters to "Nowcast" in order to handle different publication lags, which is similar to some data not being available from some markets. I would take extra care that the results makes sense.

Comment: The approach in the paper that you reference is indeed very interesting and close to our paper. However, they use a $VAR(1)$ mode, in which auto-correlations do not vanish but just decay. We chose a $VMA(1)$  model as there the autocorrelations vanish after one time step. If autocorrelation comes from non-contemporaneous trading then it should vanish after one day. In practice a $VMA(1)$ and a $VAR(1)$ model will give similar results in most applications.

Comment: I tend to shy away from moving average models and just increase the number of lags in a autoregressive model, but what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: Just one more and last comment: if you look at the preprint above page 5 formula 1.6 then you see how the regression of returns on lagged returns is represented. This looks at first glance like $VAR(1)$ but when you analyze the residual then this can not be shown to be White Noise, which it should be for $VAR(1)$.

Comment: I don't keep my promise, one more comment: you are right, that the calibration of $VAR(1)$ is more intuitive (it cna be done by a regression) than the calibration of $VMA(1)$. Our experiments in this context gave good results for the calibration of $VMA(1)$ too.

Comment: I've read about the use of a garch process, what do you thik about it ?

Comment: While GARCH is a good approach to modeling volatility, I wouldn't make things too complicated when dealing with data synchronization. That being said, in the regression approach I linked to, the synchronized series is a function of another series, which for equities would have time-varying volatility. So if you fit a GARCH to the synchronized series it would also have time-varying volatility, most likely.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for the covariance structure, then the simplest asynchronous estimator is that from [Hayashi-Yoshida](https://doi.org/10.3150/bj/1116340299) - [Corsi-Audrino](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947309003636) which avoids any bias from synchronization. There is a wide literature developed on top, from dealing with microstructure noise&autocorrelation to improving efficiency, but the basic form should usually suffice in practice.

VMA&c and filters are surely also feasible, but sometimes overkill, just like classical missing data methods such as expectation maximization.